# Yii2 Выборка данных кэша по тегам

Tags: yii2, кэширование

Есть конструкция, типа

```
foreach ($tableAll as $record) {
    Yii::$app->cache->set(
        [$record['val1'], $record['val2']],
        $record,
        360,
        new TagDependency([ 'tags' => [ $record['val1'], $record['val2'] ] ])
    );
}
```

Вопрос в следующем - как мне выбрать данные не по ключу кэша, а по одному из тегов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, кэш - это не SQL-решение и, будучи унифицированным, не умеет искать по атрибутам, а просто является KV-хранилищем, которые умеет искать только по конкретному ключу.

Тем не менее, решение *проблемы* существует, и заключается в смене подхода к работе с данными. В случае с классическим SQL используется подход *pull-on-demand* - данные запрашиваются, ищутся и агрегируются в момент необходимости. В NoSQL-мире, который нацелен на решение проблем большого количества потребителей, активно продвигается подход *push-on-change*, которая заключается в *подготовке данных к использованию в момент их обновления*. Если мы сравним с классическим SQL, то вместо ситуаций с джойном и поиском по атрибуту будут запрашиваться уже подготовленные данные (как по джойну, так и по поиску атрибуту), которые будут подготовлены в момент обновления данных.
Таким образом, я вам рекомендую подготавливать в кэше необходимые списки в момент обновления данных: в тот момент, когда добавляется новая запись, для нее в кэше создается своя собственная запись, а также обновляются все записи-списки по тегам записи - в эти списки добавляется идентификатор записи. На псевдокоде это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
db.put record
cache.put 'record:my-super-model:id:' + record.id, record
for tag in record.tags
  cache_id = 'record:my-super-model:tag:' + tag
  tag_records = cache.get cache_id ?: []
  tag_records.append record.id
  cache.put cache_id, tag_records
```

После этого у вас уже есть подготовленные данные, и для выборки всех записей по тегу нужно просто сделать два обращения к кешу:

```
records = cache.get 'record:my-super-model:tag:' + tag
// блок с обработкой несуществующей в кэше записи опущен
identifiers = ['record:my-super-model:id:' + id for id in records]
return cache.multi_get identifiers
```

Comment: Отличный подход, как раз то, что нужно. Благодарю.